# Create table with new column based on different column in another table in one statement

Tags: ms-access

In MS Access I want to create a new table and add a column to that table (T2) and set the value based on values in another table (T1). I need that column (CO) in T2 that gets a value of 'West' if the value in T1.LOC = 'www' and 'East' if the value in T1.LOC = 'eee'

```sql
Select LOC INTO T2 FROM T1;
UPDATE T2 from SET CO= SWITCH(T1.LOC ='www', 'West', T1.LOC ='eee', 'East', TRUE, 'XXXX';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use that `Switch()` expression as a derived column for `CO` in your "make table" query.

```sql
SELECT
    T1.LOC,
    Switch
        (
            T1.LOC ='www', 'West',
            T1.LOC ='eee', 'East',
            TRUE, 'XXXX'
        ) AS CO
INTO T2
FROM T1;
```